# TCP Socket with Python server and Java client

Tags: java, python, string, sockets

I am trying to exchange some string data between a Python Server (ideally, a Raspberry Pi with some device connected through GPIO) and a Java Client (again, the main target would be an Android app). The following code, anyway, is running on a standard local PC.

This is the code for the server, taken (and slightly modified) from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socketserver.html):

```
import socketserver
import datetime

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        answer = now
        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        print("Read!")
        if str(self.data) == 'date':
            answer = now.date()
        elif str(self.data) == 'time':
            answer = now.time()

        self.wfile.write((str(answer)+"\n").encode('utf-8'))
        print("Sent!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        print("Server is running on {}, port {}".format(HOST, PORT))
        server.serve_forever()
```

The Java client is the following:

```
public class SocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            out.println("date".getBytes());
            String resp = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + resp);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SocketTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
}
```

No exception is thrown whatsoever, it just gets stuck waiting for the response on the client side, and I can never see the `"Read!"` message on the server side.

The `"date".getBytes()` comes from somewhere on the net where I found that the Python sockets expect bytes (UTF-8), but in Java I'm sending strings directly, so it might be wrong.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnes out, it was a flushing problem.

Apparently, the buffer is not flushed when the end of line is reached (which is how I was expecting it to behave).

Adding a simple `out.flush()` solved the problem.